# What does the "->" operator mean in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-keyword

Could someone explain to me what the "->" means in C++?

Examples if you can, they help me understand better.
Thanks.

Comment: +1 I don't know why people are downvoting you.  It's a basic question, but so what?  That doesn't make it bad.

Comment: +1: It's a simple question, but it's very hard to search the web for such characters. You'd probably benefit from [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/78845), though.

Comment: True, it is a basic question. But it's also a question that would *easily* be answered by looking at *any* book on C++ or C. Google is not the *only* research that people should do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a shortcut for dereference followed by property access (or method invocation).

In code,  here are some examples of this equivalence:

```
Foo *foo;

// field access
foo->bar = 10;
(*foo).bar = 10;

// method invocation
foo->baz();
(*foo).baz();
```

This is especially convenient when you have a long sequence of these. For example, if you have a singly linked list data structure in which each element has a pointer to the next, the following are equivalent ways of finding the fifth element (but one looks much nicer):

```
linked_list *head, *fifth;
fifth = head->next->next->next->next;
fifth = (*(*(*(*head).next).next).next).next;
```

Comment: It is much more convenient. Here's a code snippet from some real code, given a pointer to a resource descriptor (`rd`), it gets the friendly name of the server that hosts the resource: `rd->resource->GetServer()->GetFriendlyName()`. The `GetServer` function returns a pointer to the server that hosts the resource. `resource` is a member of the resource descriptor structure. Think how ugly that would be in `(*).` form.

Comment: as with almost all operators in C++ you should make the addendum that both `*` and `->` can be overloaded so `(*a).b` and `a->b` although usually the same have no guarantee of being equivalent unless `a` is a pointer.

Answer (score 7):

It's often called the "member access" operator. Basically, `a->b` is a nicer way to write `(*a).b`. You can think of `a->b` as "access the `b` member/function in the object `a` points to". You can read it aloud (or think it to yourself) as "`a` member access `b`".

In a random sample of structured C++ code I just checked (from several different projects written by different people), 10% of lines of code (not counting headers) contained at least one member access operator.

Comment: There is a conspicuous lack of mention of the term "pointer" in your answer. Yes, operator-> can be overloaded, but even then, that's only really done for objects that mimic pointers.

Comment: @NicolBolas You do usually (that is, almost always) use the member access object on something that is either literally a pointer or an instance of a class that acts like a pointer. I do say that it accesses the "object `a` *points* to".

Comment: Yes, you say that, but you then say you can read it as "`a` member access `b`". That's not possible if `a` is a naked pointer, since pointers don't actually have members. It's "`a` dereference, then member access `b`". And "dereference" doesn't make sense without talking about pointers.

Comment: @NicolBolas Pointers don't have members, but what pointers access do have members. Hence it's a "member *access*" operation. (That is, it allows you to access a member.)

Answer (score 3):

The `->` operator is used with a pointer (or pointer-like object) on the LHS and a structure or class member on the RHS (`lhs->rhs`).  It is generally equivalent to `(*lhs).rhs`, which is the other way of accessing a member.  It is more convenient if you ignore the Law of Demeter and need to write `lhs->mid->rhs` (which is generally easier to read than `(*(*lhs).mid).rhs`).

You can overload the `->` operator, and smart pointers often do.  <s>AFAIK</s> You cannot overload the `.` operator.

Comment: You are correct that `.` cannot be overloaded (along with `.*`, `::`, and `'?:`).